# Multiple field Settings not appearing on an entity referenced field

Tags: entities

I have a content gallery with a multiple selection entity referenced field to a biblio content. I added the image field to the biblio. Created a view for the gallery, and I'm able to display all the images form the referenced entity.

But for the gallery to work, I need the first image to display only, and when user selects an image a popup appears.

What I'm missing is for the first image to appear only.when configuring the entity referenced field, the multiple field settings is not appearing. Is there another way to do the following or am I missing something?

Comment: Where do you want to display only the first entity referenced field ? Your post need a litle bit more details.

Comment: I'm trying to create a gallery, so when user selects an image, a slider would popup.

Comment: Okay, I understand a little bit more. Maybe you can do this with display none in CSS. You have to manage to get a class on your first image

Comment: I guess that's the best way, if the multiple field is not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a relationship to the referenced entity and then add a filter where field_FIELD_NAME:delta = 0. Then either add fields that belong to the referenced entity using the relationship or add a "rendered entity" field using the relationship.

Comment: This way works, but it stops all other images to appear on colorbox.